# What are the "cpu" and "memory" options on the mount command?

Tags: linux, mount, cgroups

I found some mount commands in a shell script:

```
mount -t cgroup -o memory none /path/XXX
mount -t cgroup -o cpu    none /path/XXX
```

The question is what does the cpu/memory option mean?
I search the mount man and Googled it, but not find some answer.

Comment: Try doing `man mount_cgroup` or searching for `mount cgroup options "-o memory" "-o cpu"` (with the quotes).

Answer (score 4):

You're looking in the wrong place, because this isn't really to do with the mount command itself. What you're doing is mounting a special filesystem, in this case, a *cgroups hierarchy*, and the options happen to be how you attach different cgroup subsystems like cpu or memory.

Red Hat* has some good documentation on 
[cgroups in general](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch01.html) and [the mount options in specific](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-Creating_a_Hierarchy_and_Attaching_Subsystems.html).

* my employer